# Ionic: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Call from Ionic app using $http GET to Wordpress REST API is failing with error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mywordpressdomain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories. Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I noticed that request header has:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers:token
```

I tried removing the header in my $http get request.

```
$http({
 method: 'GET',
 url: url,
 headers: { 'Access-Control-Request-Headers': undefined },
})
```

But the Access-Control-Request-Headers: token is still present in the request header. Seems like headers has no effect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You must allow CORS on your server, this is not an issue of your angular app.

Answer (score 0):

for not having any CORS issue related with http request on your localhost while developing set skipAuthorization: true... just do like this:

'$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://yoururl.com/yourrequest',
  skipAuthorization: true
})'